MS Paint crashes when my electron desktop application is installed (modifies registry for overlay icons)
I'm working on an electron desktop application that modifies the Windows registry to display small overlay icons on files in Windows Explorer. The app works as expected in terms of showing the overlay icons, but I noticed that MS Paint crashes on Save prompt after my application is installed.
My application modifies the registry to register a shell extension for overlay icons. Below is a general outline of what my app does:

Adds keys to the registry for overlay icon handlers.
The app uses a custom DLL for the icon overlays.

MS Paint works fine before the installation, so I suspect the issue might be related to how my application interacts with the system registry or shell.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with registry modifications affecting other applications like MS Paint? Are there any best practices or known conflicts when registering shell extensions for overlay icons that might be causing this crash?
Additional Info:
OS: Found on Windows 11. On Windows 10, MS Paint does not crash on the SAVE/OPEN prompt.
Application type: Electron app with a native DLL.
Logs from event viewer:
Faulting application name: mspaint.exe
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll

The crash only occurs after installation, removing the app resolves the issue.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
